# How to define a function based on vaues of multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, function, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a datafile as follows:

| Activity | Hazard | Condition | consequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| welding | fire | chamber | high |
| painting | falling | none | medium |

I need to create a fifth column based on the values in the activity, hazard, condition, and consequence columns. The conditions are as follows

if the activity column includes "working" or "performing" return 'none'
if the condition column includes 'none' return 'none'
else return datafile.Hazard.map(str) + " is " + datafile.Condition.map(str) + " impact " datafile.consequence.map(str)

I wrote the following code using regular expressions and dictionaries. But it didn't provide an answer. It is really appreciated if someone can give an answer

```
Dt1 = ['working','performing duties']
Dt2 = ["none"]

Dt1_regex = "|".join(Dt1)
Dt2_regex = "|".join(Dt2)

def clean(x):
    if datafile.Activity.str.contains (Dt1_regex, regex=True) | datafile.Condition.str.contains(Dt2_regex, regex=True):
        return 'none'
    else:
        return datafile.Hazard.map(str) + " is " + datafile.Condition.map(str)" impact " datafile.consequence.map(str)

datafile['combined'] = datafile.apply(clean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a bunch of conditions, and a list of the associated values when the conditions are `true`. You can then create the new column as shown in the example below:

#### Conditions:

- When `Activity == 'working'` **OR** `Activity == 'performing'` - set to `none`
- When `Condition == 'none'` - set to `none`

Otherwise set to:

`df.Hazard` + `' is '` + `df.Condition` + `' impact '` + `df.consequence`

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Activity': ['welding', 'painting', 'working'],
                    'Hazard': ['fire', 'falling', 'drowning'],
                    'Condition': ['chamber', 'none', 'wet'],
                    'consequence': ['high', 'medium', 'high']})

# Create your conditions
conditions = [
    (df['Activity'] == 'working') | (df['Activity'] == 'performing'),
    (df['Condition'] == 'none')
    ]

# create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
values = ['none', 'none']

# Create the new column based on the conditions and values
df['combined'] = np.select(conditions, values, default = "x")
df.loc[df['combined'] == 'x', 'combined'] = df.Hazard + ' is ' + df.Condition + " impact " + df.consequence

print(df)
```

#### Output:

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code which also gave me the correct answer.

```
Dt1 = ["working", "performing duties"]
Dt1_regex = "|".join(Dt1)

conditions = [
    (datafile.Activity.str.contains(Dt1_regex,regex=True)),
    (datafile.Condition.str.contains('none')==True),
    (datafile.Activity.str.contains(Dt1_regex,regex=False))|(datafile.Condition.str.contains('none')==False)
]
values = ['none', 'none', datafile.Hazard + ' is ' + datafile.Condition + " impact " + datafile.consequence]
datafile['combined'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).